# how do I divide columns by range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need your help in using case when function. (probably)

I have a data for daily visits to the server.  However, I would like to group these user data by their visit frequency. So that I can divide them into groups who visits less than 5 times, 5 to 10 times, and over 10 times. I hear that case when function could help this but I don't have any clue how to run that.

Set out below is the query that I used to derive daily visits, and the following table is the output for the query. If there's anyone who knows how to write that query accordingly, do help me out. Much appreciated.

```
select aid, count(result_type) as "daily_visits"


FROM [DBO].[TB_SESSION_LOG]

WHERE
    log_dt >= @start_date and
    log_dt < @end_date


group by svc_cd, aid
order by svc_cd, aid
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EbFp.png)

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Comment: You have `scv_cd` in the `group by` but not the `select`.  That is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Try `case` and sub query or [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql):

```sql
    select aid, count(result_type) as "daily_visits",
     case
      when count(result_type) < 5 then 0
      when count(result_type) between 5 and 10 then 1
      when count(result_type) > 10 then 2
     end as grp

    FROM [DBO].[TB_SESSION_LOG]
    WHERE
        log_dt >= @start_date and
        log_dt < @end_date

    group by svc_cd, aid
    order by svc_cd, aid
```

Note that I didn't test the above query but it should work or may need small fixes.

Comment: Another way is using a `VIEW`, create a view for then above query (without subquery or CTE, just add the `case`s) then select from your view by grouping with the count of visits.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
Invalid column name 'aid'.
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

this is something that pops out of my window after running that above.

Comment: I've updated the SQL, removed the outer query, I think it should work this way also. If you can share the table definition and some sample data as `insert` statements then I can look into it, it is difficult to guess and takes time to prepare.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a grouping using `CASE` like this:

```
  SELECT aid, COUNT(result_type) as daily_visits,
         (CASE WHEN COUNT(result_type) < 5 THEN 'less than 5'
               WHEN COUNT(result_type) < 10 THEN 'between 5 and 10'
               ELSE '10 or more
         END) as grp
  FROM [DBO].[TB_SESSION_LOG]
  WHERE log_dt >= @start_date and
        log_dt < @end_date
  GROUP BY aid
```

I'm not sure if you want additional processing, but this seems to address your question.

Note:  This removes `svc_cd` from the query.  It does not appear to be being used.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're looking for something like this

```
with dv_cte(aid, daily_visits) as (
    select aid, count(result_type)
    from [DBO].[TB_SESSION_LOG]
    where log_dt >= @start_date and
          log_dt < @end_date
    group by svc_cd, aid)
select
  case when daily_visits < 5 then '<5'
       when daily_visits < 10 then '>5 and <10'
       else '10+' end as grp,
  count(*) grp_count
from dv_cte
group by
  case when daily_visits < 5 then '<5'
       when daily_visits < 10 then '>5 and <10'
       else '10+' end;
```